# What do these parens/comma mean in this value assignment?

Tags: javascript

I am working on porting the GraphQL reference implementation from javascript to C#.  I came across something I don't understand or know how to reason about so I'm unsure the correct way to port it.  The code in question is shown below or you can go to this link to see the code in the repo [parseConstArgument function in parse.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/271e23e13ec093e7ffb844e7ffaf340ab92f053e/src/language/parser.js#L448):

```
    function parseConstArgument(lexer: Lexer<*>): ArgumentNode {
  const start = lexer.token;
  return {
    kind: Kind.ARGUMENT,
    name: parseName(lexer),
    value: (expectToken(lexer, TokenKind.COLON), parseConstValue(lexer)),
    loc: loc(lexer, start),
  };
}
```

So what I am not understanding is the line making the assignment to the **value** field.  The **expectToken** function either returns an **Token** object or throws an error.  The **parseConstValue** function returns a **ValueNode** object.  The **value** field itself expects to be assigned a **ValueNode**.

So what is this doing? Does it first exectute **expectToken** to make use of the possible error and if no error thrown it throws away the **Token** returned and then assigns the result of **parseConstValue** to the **value** field?  That is my best guess, but I'm not 100% sure and I don't know how to describe this syntax to do a Google search on it.

Another similarly confusing field assignment is like the one here [parseValueLiteral function in parse.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/271e23e13ec093e7ffb844e7ffaf340ab92f053e/src/language/parser.js#L554)

```
return {
    kind: Kind.INT,
    value: ((token.value: any): string),
    loc: loc(lexer, token),
  };
```

Again my confusion is with the assignment to the value field.  In this case **value** expects a string, so I am just assuming this "weird" syntax is just assigning **token.value**, which is a string, to the **value** field.

It would be much appreciated if someone could explain this and possible point to documentation on these javascript features.  I really would like to make sure I am not introducing bugs in my port because I don't understand the javascript syntax.

Comment: The second one looks like a TypeScript type cast

Comment: [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: @Bergi Yea it there is a lot of TypeScript feel to the codebase but all the files are .js not .ts and there is no tsconfig.json file that I can find.

Comment: @adiga Thanks I was on that page earlier but I didnt look all the way at the bottom.  The return (x += 1, x); // the same as return ++x; example explains what I am seeing in my first example and apparently it is working like I thought.  It evaluates the first part of the expression then assigns the second part of the expression to the value field.

Comment: @GregCobb It must be TypeScript (or Flow or some other type annotation extension), as `((token.value: any): string)` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi I finshed porting the parser file and in looking at what next to tackle i noticed at the root of the project they have an index.js file that references flow so it looks like it is Flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value: (expectToken(lexer, TokenKind.COLON), parseConstValue(lexer))
```

Appears to have the purpose of always executing `expectToken(lexer, TokenKind.COLON)` before `parseConstValue(lexer)` by wrapping the two function calls separated by the comma `,` operator with parentheses, to form an expression, where the resulting value set will always by the return value of `parseConstValue(lexer)`.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, but do you have any explanation as to the reason for the way they wrote the second example I showed?  I assume they are just assigning token.value to the value field, but I can't figure out why they wrote it that way.

Comment: @GregCobb Technically, for the reason stated at the answer. For the precise reason you can try to contact the author of the code for an explanation of why they wrote the code using that specific pattern.

Comment: I think it is a Flow thing.  I don't really want to learn Flow, but I think my assumptions are correct that it is just a type annotation.

Comment: @GregCobb Not sure. Have not tried Flow. Have you asked one of the maintainers of Flow?